# In which directory should I install Google Cloud's SDK (and SDKs in general)

Tags: macos, google-cloud-sdk

Currently / For Some Reason, Google Cloud's SDK folder is located directly in my home `/Users/myname` directory. I like to keep my home directory clean of any files + folders outside the main couple of core directories: `Applications`, `Documents`, `Downloads`, `Dropbox`, etc. An SDK seems like something that should be installed in the macbook's initial `/Library` directory, not somewhere in `Users/myname`, and I'd like to move this folder to where it belongs.

As a follow up question - how should I go about this? Should I simply drag and drop the folder into a new location, or uninstall and reinstall entirely? Also, other than updating my .bash_profile, is there anything else to be done when moving the SDK location so that it still works?

Thanks!

Comment: `when checking my $PATH variable` The expansion of `PATH` is not something you execute. There is nothing wrong in the behavior you are observing. Maybe instead you want to print the value of `PATH` with `echo "$PATH"`. The error message is what it says - you try to execute the value of `PATH` and such command does not exists. A command may exists in one of the doublepoint separated paths inside the `PATH` variable, for example `sh` may exists in `/usr/bin`

Comment: Thank you for letting me know this - I've updated the post. My `bash_profile` and `PATH` still seem off though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `google-cloud-sdk` directory is in your `HOME` because that's where you extracted it :)

From the [quickstart instructions](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-macos):

> Extract the archive to any location on your file system; preferably, your home directory.

So your home directory is the recommended location, but you can put it wherever you'd like. If you run the `install.sh` script the SDK will be configured in your shell pointing to that location.

If you don't want it taking up space in your home directory you could try `/usr/local/lib`, which is a [typical location for "libraries"](https://superuser.com/a/1469586/16275).